# Linear layout within relativelayout not perfect the fullscreen fit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-fullscreen

Linerlayout will be not fit in full screen white background color displaying ..
Any ideas on making both sides Fit in fullscreen?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"\>
 <Button
android:id="@+id/bClose"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:onClick="cancelActivity"
android:text="@string/x_close" 
android:textColor="#FFF"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
/>


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/preview_frag"
android:focusable="true">
<requestFocus />
</LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it using webview? adjust webview by implementing padding and margin in it.... use -(negative) values

Comment: is this helpful?

Comment: Thank you so much...u save my time..  its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works totally fine. Try using match_parent instead of fill_parent.
Check if the image has white space.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bClose"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_event_white_24dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="close"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <requestFocus />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout is correct, probably the issue is in the fragment layout since your `LinearLayout` seems to be a fragment container.
Check if your fragment_layout has some margin or padding.
Also as a suggest you should change from `fill_parent` to `match_parent`

Comment: Your `LinearLayout` has `android:id="@+id/preview_frag"` so I assume that you are using this layout as a fragment container, check the layout of the fragment that you are adding/replacing here, maybe the issue is in that fragment layout, for instance margin/padding, wrong gravity...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bClose"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="cancelActivity"
        android:text="@string/x_close" 
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/preview_frag"
        android:focusable="true">
        <requestFocus />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have the close button on top of the `LinearLayout`, you can try using the parent view as `FrameLayout`, something like so :-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Output will be something like below:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

replace height  and width property fill_parent to match_parent remove gravity from LinearLayout try above code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <Button
android:id="@+id/bClose"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:onClick="cancelActivity"
android:text="@string/x_close" 
android:textColor="#FFF"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
/>


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/preview_frag">
</LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: then definitely these white spaces come from other linked layout share layout which called in your linear layout

Comment: I don't understand...can u pls explain elaborate

Comment: I mean share where you were wrote xml code which contains that ImageView and other main content..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bClose"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blockclose"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="cancelActivity"
    android:text="x_close"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/preview_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <requestFocus />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

if you are using imageview try using

> `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score -1):

i also face the same problem, by giving negative margin values its works fine for me
example code

```
<body style='margin:-0.5px;'>
```

i hope above code will works for you

Comment: ya me too got the output :) nice